# why nuxt.js global css on config is not working?

Tags: nuxt.js

I try to put css files on assets 
assest/css/style.css
and call it to my nuxt.config.js
but it is not working i need to use global css not scoped css

can someone help me?

when i add css
in the nuxt.config.js

```
   /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
      '~assets/css/style.css'
  ],
```

its not working ? 
nuxt version 2

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: it should work, provide full not working code otherwise

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? Seriously, changes in nuxt.config.js aren't applied unless you restart nuxt. Make some ridiculously obvious change in your CSS that you simply can't miss, like setting the background of the body to `#0000ff !important` or something, just so you can be certain it's not just some other stylesheet you're loading that overrides your own CSS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I came across the same issue and solved it putting the file path to my css inside the css options and inside modules. Example code below. Hope it helps. I'm also using [nuxt-sass-resources-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-sass-resources-loader) to load my sass files globally.

```
css: [
  '@/assets/css/reset.css',
  '@/assets/css/main.scss',
],
modules: [
 [
  'nuxt-sass-resources-loader',
  ['./assets/css/main.scss'],
  ['./assets/css/reset.css']
 ]
],
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply restart the server. Adding the code to the module should not be necessary.

Comment: After modifying the `nuxt.config`, a server restart (`Ctrl + C`, `npm run dev`) is always necessary.