# Why my global style and js files inside nuxt.config.js doesn't work?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

How i can use my global style.css and my js files inside assets folder in a nuxt project? 
I am currently doing so inside my nuxt.config.js but it doesn't work:

For CSS file:

```
css: [
  '~assets/css/style.css'
],
```

For JS file

```
script: [
 {
    src: '~assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js',
    body: true
 }
]
```

Comment: Does your script array have a closing bracket?

Comment: yes, I forgot to put it here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why nuxt.js global css on config is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53236783/why-nuxt-js-global-css-on-config-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust it according to the documentation
https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-css/:

```
'@/assets/css/style.css'
```

The same should help for the JS file.